# Hibernate mapping error: duplicate foreign key

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Entity Class UserExtraDetails with having `one to one relationship` with APP_USER with column `SSO_ID`

```
package com.eportal.models;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name = "userdetails")
public class userExtraDetails implements Serializable {

    @Column(name = "Address", nullable = true)
    private String Address;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SSO_ID", nullable = false)
    private String ssoId;

    @Column(name = "City", nullable = true)
    private String City;

    @Column(name = "Country", nullable = true)
    private String Country;

    @Column(name = "Postal_Code", nullable = true)
    private String Postal_Code;

    @Column(name = "about_me", nullable = true)
    private String about_me;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APP_USER", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SSO_ID") })
    private User user;

    public String getAbout_me() {
        return about_me;
    }

    public String getSsoId() {
        return ssoId;
    }

    public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
        this.ssoId = ssoId;
    }

    public void setAbout_me(String about_me) {
        this.about_me = about_me;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public String getCity() {
        return City;
    }

    public void setCity(String city) {
        City = city;
    }

    public String getCountry() {
        return Country;
    }

    public void setCountry(String country) {
        Country = country;
    }

    public String getPostal_Code() {
        return Postal_Code;
    }

    public void setPostal_Code(String postal_Code) {
        Postal_Code = postal_Code;
    }

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Entity Class `User` with a `one to one relationship` with userdetails with column `SSO_ID`

```html
package com.eportal.models;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import javax.persistence.CascadeType;
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.FetchType;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.JoinColumn;
import javax.persistence.JoinTable;
import javax.persistence.ManyToMany;
import javax.persistence.OneToOne;
import javax.persistence.Table;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty;

@Entity
@Table(name = "APP_USER")
public class User implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "SSO_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private String ssoId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "PASSWORD", nullable = false)
    private String password;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "FIRST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String firstName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "LAST_NAME", nullable = false)
    private String lastName;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name = "EMAIL", nullable = false)
    private String email;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "userdetails", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "SSO_ID") })
    private userExtraDetails details;

    @NotEmpty
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "APP_USER_USER_PROFILE", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "USER_ID") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "USER_PROFILE_ID") })
    private Set<UserProfile> userProfiles = new HashSet<UserProfile>();

    public userExtraDetails getDetails() {
        return details;
    }

    public void setDetails(userExtraDetails details) {
        this.details = details;
    }

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getSsoId() {
        return ssoId;
    }

    public void setSsoId(String ssoId) {
        this.ssoId = ssoId;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public Set<UserProfile> getUserProfiles() {
        return userProfiles;
    }

    public void setUserProfiles(Set<UserProfile> userProfiles) {
        this.userProfiles = userProfiles;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((id == null) ? 0 : id.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((ssoId == null) ? 0 : ssoId.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (!(obj instanceof User))
            return false;
        User other = (User) obj;
        if (id == null) {
            if (other.id != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!id.equals(other.id))
            return false;
        if (ssoId == null) {
            if (other.ssoId != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!ssoId.equals(other.ssoId))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    /*
     * DO-NOT-INCLUDE passwords in toString function. It is done here just for
     * convenience purpose.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User [id=" + id + ", ssoId=" + ssoId + ", password=" + password + ", firstName=" + firstName
                + ", lastName=" + lastName + ", email=" + email + "]";
    }

}
```

```html
18:31:55.434 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table APP_USER add constraint FK_1wjx4w75wu94ftp6jvt35krf0 foreign key (user_id) references APP_USER
18:31:55.434 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - There is already an object named 'FK_1wjx4w75wu94ftp6jvt35krf0' in the database.
18:31:55.438 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table APP_USER add constraint FK_hqk6uc88j3imq8u9jhro36vt3 foreign key (SSO_ID) references userdetails
18:31:55.438 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_hqk6uc88j3imq8u9jhro36vt3". The conflict occurred in database "CloudDB", table "dbo.userdetails", column 'SSO_ID'.
18:31:55.440 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table APP_USER_USER_PROFILE add constraint FK_brmce0t584euix4wb4rursf1q foreign key (USER_ID) references APP_USER
18:31:55.440 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - There is already an object named 'FK_brmce0t584euix4wb4rursf1q' in the database.
18:31:55.442 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000388: Unsuccessful: alter table userdetails add constraint FK_pffebqmeoi5qdq5g63w450h1i foreign key (SSO_ID) references APP_USER
18:31:55.442 [localhost-startStop-1] ERROR o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - Column 'APP_USER.id' is not the same data type as referencing column 'userdetails.SSO_ID' in foreign key 'FK_pffebqmeoi5qdq5g63w450h1i'.
18:31:55.442 [localhost-startStop-1] INFO  o.h.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate - HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

The following error is shown:

> Unsuccessful: alter table APP_USER add constraint
>   FK_1wjx4w75wu94ftp6jvt35krf0 foreign key (user_id) references APP_USER
>
> There is already an object named 'FK_1wjx4w75wu94ftp6jvt35krf0' in the
>   database.
>
> Unsuccessful: alter table APP_USER add constraint
>   FK_hqk6uc88j3imq8u9jhro36vt3 foreign key (SSO_ID) references
>   userdetails
>
> The ALTER TABLE statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
>   "FK_hqk6uc88j3imq8u9jhro36vt3". The conflict occurred in database
>   "CloudDB", table "dbo.userdetails", column 'SSO_ID'.
>
> Unsuccessful: alter table APP_USER_USER_PROFILE add constraint
>   FK_brmce0t584euix4wb4rursf1q foreign key (USER_ID) references APP_USER
>
> There is already an object named 'FK_brmce0t584euix4wb4rursf1q' in the
>   database.
>
> Unsuccessful: alter table userdetails add constraint
>   FK_pffebqmeoi5qdq5g63w450h1i foreign key (SSO_ID) references APP_USER
>
> Column 'APP_USER.id' is not the same data type as referencing column
>   'userdetails.SSO_ID' in foreign key 'FK_pffebqmeoi5qdq5g63w450h1i'.

Comment: Is it possible that you try to create the tables everytime Hibernate starts up? There is a config property called ``hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto``. What is it set to?

Comment: @Matt hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update

Comment: When does this error occur? I'm not sure it works well to map a bidirectional relationship twice, it's the purpose of the `mappedBy` attribute of any *To* annotation

Comment: @HBo  error occurred at startup of Project